# How to show required message of h:selectOneMenu with a default select option?

Tags: jsf-2

I am facing one issue with selectOneMenu.  I need to display list of items in a drop down and it is a required field.

In that drop down the first value is **"Select"**.  If the user doesn't select any question, then I need to display an error message like **"Select any question"**.

Can anyone give me solution?

Answer (score 16):

Just set the item value of the first item to `null`. You shouldn't set it with the value of the label.

E.g.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.question}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please select a question">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.questions}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: I consider that <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bean.question}" /> with bean.question = "Please...." is better because in the logic server doesn't change with the view changes. With if (!question.equals("Please...")){do...}

Answer (score -1):

You can also create a validator.

1)

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="giftValue" value="#{yourController.giftDO.giftValue}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{yourController.giftDO.giftValueMap}" />
            <f:validator validatorId="selectOneMenuValidator"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu> 
    <h:message for="giftValue" errorStyle="color:red"/>
    //where giftValue enum willcontail the word "Select"
```

2) Create the SelectOneMenuValidator.java

```
public class SelectOneMenuValidator implements Validator {
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.faces.validator.Validator#validate(javax.faces.context.FacesContext, javax.faces.component.UIComponent, java.lang.Object)
     */

    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent arg1, Object value)
            throws ValidatorException {

         String giftValue = (String)value;

         if(giftValue != null && giftValue.toUpperCase().equals("SELECT")){ 
             FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();  
             message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);  
             message.setSummary("Please Select a question!");  
             message.setDetail("Please Select a question!");              
             context.addMessage("Please Select a question!", message);      
             throw new ValidatorException(message); 
         }

    }
}
```

3) Add the validator to the faces-config.xml

```
<validator>  
     <validator-id>selectOneMenuValidator</validator-id>  
     <validator-class>net.roseindia.validations.SelectOneMenuValidator</validator-class>  
 </validator>
```

Comment: Just a word of warning: Roseindia.net is **world's worst** resource as to learning Java EE. Please add that site to your blacklist. In this particular case the Roseindia.net article author clearly isn't aware how the `required/requiredMessage` attributes can/should be used. Also, that `context.addMessage()` part is in this context pure nonsense. This all is very misleading to JSF starters who later then unrightfully complain that JSF is "so confusing, hard, and bad" while it are just those "lecturing" resources which are bad. Please get a decent book/resource/tutorial.